# jQuery ajax success not changing local variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax in order to check if an image is there before trying to load it. I have it mostly working, but I'm setting a variable inside of the error: and success: tags in ajax, and it isn't changing my img variable. Is there any way to effect the rest of the function through these tags?

```
function getImage(imageNum)
{
var img;
$.ajax({
    url:imageLocation + imageNum + '.png',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        img = 0;
    },
    success: function()
    {
        var img = $('<img />', {
            src: imageLocation + imageNum + '.png',
            class: 'image',
            id:'image' + imageNum});
        return img;
    }
});
console.log(img);
return img;
}
```

Alright so I would rather use just the image tag if there's no reason to use AJAX. The problem is that the variable isn't changing something within my function. Here's an example.

```
function getImage(imageNum)
{
    var img;
    var success = 10;
    var img = $('<img />', {
        src: imageLocation + imageNum + '.png',
        class: 'image',
        id:'image' + imageNum,
        success: function () { 
            success = 1
        },
        error: function () { 
            success = 0;
        }
    });

    console.log(success);
    if(success = 1)
        return img;
    else
        return 0;
}

function loadImage(imageNum)
{
    var img = getImage(imageNum);
    if(img != 0)
    {
        $('#slider').imagesLoaded( function () {
            $("#slider").append(img);
            loadImage(imageNum + 1);
        });
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: Why not write some custom PHP that can check and reply to your ajax call?

Comment: the issue here is that `$.ajax` is asynchronous: returning happends immediately (before the server sends the img data and `success` is called.

Comment: @TheZ Too complicated to just check if an image is available.

Comment: @bokonic If that's the case, how can you use the ajax success call? Wouldn't it always return before the server responds?

Comment: sorry that was worded badly: what I meant is that the way ajax works, you only get your data when either `success()` or `error()` is called (by jQuery, which is triggered by the receipt of data from the server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.ajax is asynchronous, so you're calling `console.log` before the call completes. You can't return like this when your code is a synchronous.

You have to instead call your other code inside success() -- example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '',
  data: '',
  success: function(data){
      codeThatNeedsImg(data);
  }
  });

function codeThatNeedsImg(img){
   console.log(img);
}
```

Comment: Hm, alright. Thank you. I'll have to try and refactor this a bit if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is not append an `<img>` element until the image itself is loaded then just do that! Create the `<img src="..." />` element and don't append it to the DOM yet. It will prompt the browser to try and get the image file. You can attach success and error event listeners to the element itself that will fire for their respective outcomes.

If you get the success event fired, then you know the image exists, and what do you know it's already preloaded so you can append it to the DOM now! If it doesn't exist the call will return sooner and the error event will fire without more overhead. I'd say it's win-win.

You can check which image it was by just reading the `src` attribute on the element in the event callback functions.

Here's an example fiddle with logic: http://jsfiddle.net/jZpNj/

Comment: I had it this way before and tried to use it to effect a variable, but it wouldn't effect anything in scope. I'm not sure what scope it was effecting, I could only get it to call an alert.

Comment: We'd need more code to debug that particular problem. (ps: Why not `error += 1;`?)

Comment: I edited my post above to have more code. (I didn't use error += 1 because I'm using it more like a bool, and I don't ever want it to be anything other than 1 or 0.)

Comment: @Lethjakman Haha, okay, I'd just use `true` or `false` values then xD

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I finally found a solution to my problem. @bokonic was pretty much right about the ajax. I kept using ajax so I could use the success call, and not append images while waiting for the error call to change the 'success' variable and end the loop. It would append about 3 extra images while waiting for that. Success would never call from loading an image, so I'm guessing it's an ajax only thing. This is what it looks like.

```
function loadImage(imageNum)
{
    $('#slider').imagesLoaded( function () {
        if(success)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:imageLocation + imageNum + '.png',
                type:'HEAD',
                error: function()
                {
                    success = false;
                },
                success: function()
                {
                    var img = $('<img />', {
                        src: imageLocation + imageNum + '.png',
                        class: 'image',
                        id:'image' + imageNum
                    });
                    $('#slider').append(img);
                    loadImage(imageNum + 1);
                }
            });
        }
        else
            return;
    });
}
```